# Missing just one date's data when sorting in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: date

When I run a query in Oracle SQL Developer to select counts by date, the date "29-JAN-19" is missing in the output even though there is data for that date.

Field name = date_added (Date_Type = DATE)

**Query**
select date_added, count(*)
from table_a
where date_added >= '28-JAN-19'
group by date_added
order by date_added

**Results**
28-JAN-19   39
30-JAN-19   29
31-JAN-19   20
--(missing '29-JAN-19')

When using a like statement to pick-up the '29-JAN-19' date:

**Query**
select date_added, count(*)
from table_a
where date_added like '%9-JAN-19%'
group by date_added
order by date_added ASC

**Result**
29-JAN-19   30
09-JAN-19   912
19-JAN-19   13

It sorts with '29-JAN-19' first which also isn't correct.

Why is it treating '29-JAN-19' as something else besides DATE when the DATA_TYPE = DATE for this field? I'm not seeing any trailing or leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select to_date(date_added, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), count(*)
from table_a
where date_added >= '28/01/2019'
group by date_added
order by date_added ASC
```